# Using Sequelize/ORM with Postgres extension types like LTREE and HSTORE

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, hstore, ltree

I have an existing app that is using Node.JS & Express & Sequelize & PostgreSQL and now new requirements came up that require using PostgreSQL extension types like `ltree` to handle tree data model and `hstore` for diverse key/value attributes on record.

So the question is can I still use Sequelize to handle the table creation, and use native queries to handle the specify extension types?

Comment: `hstore` is somewhat obsolete now that JSON support is so powerful.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you so much this was very good feedback.

Answer (score 0):

He text representation of an hstore, used for input and output, includes zero or more key => value pairs separated by commas. Some examples:

```
k => v
foo => bar, baz => whatever
"1-a" => "anything at all"
```

The next thing to do is to install Sequelize and some other dependencies:

```
npm install --save sequelize pg pg-hstore
```

to use:

```
field_name: {
        type: Sequelize.HSTORE()
      },
```

Current Functionality

```
User.findOne({
  where: {
    hstore_field: {
      fieldOne: 'some_value',
    },
  },
});
```

would produce

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE hstore_field = '"fieldOne" => "some_value"'
New functionality
User.findOne({
  where: {
    hstore_field: {
      $contains: {
        fieldOne: 'some_value',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

would produce

```
SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE hstore_field -> 'fieldOne' = 'some_value'
```

Comment: Use this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-hstore